# How to properly handle Intel virtual button events

Tags: shortcut-keys, 16.10, events

**dmesg/xinput...**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to set up shortcuts using the Windows button that windows convertibles have next to their displays and the volume buttons on the exterior. Mine is a Sony VAIO Duo 13.

The events pressed/held/released state isn't read properly and pressing the buttons once triggers the shortcut twice, this doesn't happen with other non-intel-vbtn shortcuts.

How can I make these events register proper states? Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated.

**uname -a**

```
Linux duo13 4.10.2-041002-generic #201703120131 SMP Sun Mar 12 06:33:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**xinput**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Sony Vaio Jogdial                         id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SONY0001:00 06CB:0001                     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ NTRG0F01:00 1B96:0F01                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ NTRG0F01:00 1B96:0F01 Pen                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Front Camera                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Rear Camera                               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```